# Pros & Cons of Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine

[An Updated List 21st Aug 09]

Help me Compile a  List of all the Advantages & Disadvantages of Building an Application on the Google App Engine

**Pros:**

1. No need to buy servers or server space (no maintenance).
2. Makes solving the problem of scaling easier.
3. Free up to a certain level of consumed resources.

**Cons:**

1. Locked into Google App Engine ?
2. Developers have read-only access to the filesystem on App Engine.
3. App Engine can only execute code called from an HTTP request (except for scheduled background tasks).
4. Users may upload arbitrary Python modules, but only if they are pure-Python; C and Pyrex modules are not supported.
5. App Engine limits the maximum rows returned from an entity get to 1000 rows per Datastore call.  (**Update** - App Engine now supports cursors for accessing larger queries)
6. Java applications may only use a subset (The JRE Class White List) of the classes from the JRE standard edition.
7. Java applications cannot create new threads.

**Known Issues!!** : http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list

**Hard limits**

Apps per developer -    10
Time per request -  30 sec
Files per app - 3,000
HTTP response size -    10 MB
Datastore item size -   1 MB
Application code size - 150 MB
**Update** Blob store now allows storage of files up to 50MB

**Pro or Con?**
App Engine's infrastructure removes many of the system administration and development challenges of building applications to scale to millions of hits. Google handles deploying code to a cluster, monitoring, failover, and launching application instances as necessary.

While other services let users install and configure nearly any *NIX compatible software, App Engine requires developers to use Python or Java as the programming language and a limited set of APIs. Current APIs allow storing and retrieving data from a BigTable non-relational database; making HTTP requests; sending e-mail; manipulating images; and caching. Most existing Web applications can't run on App Engine without modification, because they require a relational database.

Comment: Nice how you manage to turn features like Cron and Task Queues into 'cons'.

Comment: I am a beginner looking to use Google App Engine, I have no idea what  Cron or Task Queues does. You can help me pointing out to some beginner tutorials or books. Its a Wiki!!

Comment: a lot of this data is out of date.  app engine has added many features since this question was asked.  It also seems pretty focused on the cons.

Comment: Files per app updated to 10,000, they "document" this in their blog post: http://googleappengine.blogspot.com/2011/10/app-engine-155-sdk-release.html ;-)

Comment: I've had nothing but cons with AppEngine. Heroku has been a pleasure to work with and they have extensive documentation. Also your own VPS is the best control, but requires learning a lot of sysadmin stuff.

Comment: Expensive! I just got done installing and running an example Google has for running the google app engine and I noticed their backend services cost can add up very quickly.

Comment: May be this link could be useful. http://blog.adjutas.com/index.php/2017/01/27/benefits-of-adopting-google-app-engine/

Answer (score 14):

**Pros:**

- Scalable
- Easy and cheaper (in short term).
- Nice option for start-ups/individuals.
- Suitable for apps that just store and retrieve data.

**Cons:**

- Not suitable for CPU intensive calculations. They are slower and expensive.
- Scalability doesn't matter much cuz if an app works at Google scale then probably it makes enough money to run on its own servers.
- They have lots of limitations thrown here and there, as a result deep data analysis is difficult. Like you cannot produce a social graph using GAE.

I would say its not meant for serious businesses and expensive in long run.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed analysis, Can u help me pick out the cons & pros in detail(in the Question). Also if possible give me an upvote, i need one more to be able to upvote the answers

Comment: Answer some questions here and there so that I can upvote your answers.

Comment: About the con that scalability doesn't matter, I think it insures you against the Digg or Lifehacker effect. As in, you make a hobbyist website, which suddenly goes viral, like ytinstant.com. If you're on your own servers, no way its withstanding the media rush, but on GAE, no problem.

Comment: You could add the lack of configuration in pros. In individual setups of servers in order to achieve high security levels you have to have more than a basic understanding about it and certain experience with configurations of servers which takes time, include testing the specific configuration etc...

Comment: If you run your own servers, you need personnel to administer and maintain them. There is no need for such personnel on GAE, which is a major cost advantage for companies of any size, not just start-ups.

Comment: Most of GAE "limitations" are in the heads of developers, who simply do not know how to use it properly. You can do a very deep data analysis at extremely high speeds on GAE: the non-relational Datastore is a great platform for such tasks.

Comment: Going to echo @AndreiVolgin here, GAE excellent for doing Google scale data analysis (map/reduce, etc.) I'm not sure why you would think that one couldn't use it to produce a social graph. It can run code, yeah? Then it can produce a social graph. 

On GAE you're not going to find jQuery style plug and play modules to do everything for you, it's actually more of a tool for large, sophisticated companies and products.

Clearly you've fundamentally misunderstood the product and, these limitations, indeed, exist only in the developers mind. I recommend opening it.

Answer (score 13):

(A huge new) PRO: GAE now supports **MySQL** :
https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/

Answer (score 7):

**Pros:**

- built-in ui for unified logs
- built-in web interface for task queues
- built-in indexes on list of primary objects.

**Cons:**

- loose logs very fast
- VERY expensive
- VERY expensive
- VERY expensive
- Un-hackable. Scales because you're obligated to code in a way that scales.
- Longer development cycles. Sometimes you just want to hack something together and throw it away after 5 hors. With appengine you have to proper code it and write a lot of stuff to make it sure it scales. You can't just do a "find . | grep .avi | xargs ffmpeg -compress ...." :)
- You will loose hours trying to do the simplest tasks like sending push notifications to APNS (iPhone). Although it's fine if you only want to support android in the future.
- Terrible to make cleanups on the database. It's a HUGE pain in the ass to fix rows in the database, mainly because terribly slow, but it also requires a lot of code to loop properly within it's time constraints.
- It was a pain to port Lucene to work on it's "filesystem".
- Slow for what you pay.
- Even MORE expensive if your app has spikes of traffic. My app has those spikes if a user that has many followers makes an action and we have to push notifications to his followers. Because of that I have to keep 10 inactive servers always on ($$$$$) to handle spikes.

Appengine isn't too bad due to the fact that I have the option to burn $$$$ instead of being concerned about scalability and fixing bottlenecks to reduce server usage. Sometimes it worth it.

My advice to people starting new products is to go with hetzner.de which is where I host my other products servers. It's cheap and extremely hackable. I have one server at hetzner that is handling 3x more traffic than the product that I have on appengine. The difference in price is $100 a month versions $2700 a month!

I have system admin experience, so the bottom line is that I would never choose appengine over having my own ROOT server. Don't be that bored software engineer wanting to experiment new things instead of building great products!

Comment: after two year with app engine I think the same

Comment: Don't know about back in 2013, but GAE is quite cheap nowadays.

Comment: @TimCastelijns depends on your application. If you have an app that makes $5 for every http request, it's very cheap indeed. It's very expensive for any social network where the focus on growth and not on early monetization.

Answer (score 5):

Pro: Unlimited scalabity to your application and scales with demand.

Answer (score 4):

Con: Not available in some countries (Argentina).

### Edit

Available worldwide, but only through Google Groups for App Engine.

Comment: Definitely available there - you just need to leave a message in the group to get your account activated if you can't receive SMSes.

Comment: http://appengine.google.com/waitlist/sms_issues

Comment: voyager's link is correct, and my own recommendation is out of date - using that link is now the best way to get your account activated if you can't receive SMSes. :)

Comment: I never needed to leave a message or anything, it just worked (Buenos Aires)

Comment: @Mauricio: it has changed since last August.

Comment: @voyager: maybe, but I created my account and app over a year ago.

Answer (score 2):

I believe , GAE is yet to mature in terms of providing the basic features for serious business such as Datastore with complex primary key, java.awt.* support, these are just a few I'm naming.

Other than the free space and to build some "Hobby" websites, I strongly feel GAE is NOT the place java guys should looking into.

I'm having applications built on the JSP/Servlets and MySQL, thinking about migrating to GAE, but I find I will be spending more "value time" on the migration than just buying a space from some java hosting provider such as EATJ, etc (Sorry not marketing, just an experience).

Another big issue I've got is migration of my existing mySQL data into GAE, bulkupload is really pathetic and has no client support.

No support for Local Db to Server DB upload.

Once the GAE is ready with "all the Cons" mentioned by above, then I'll think we can look in to this migration.

Answer (score 2):

When assessing pros and cons, I think it is important to clarify the market for which one is representing. Developers looking for a cost-effective solution to help them with the steep part of their planned hockey-stick growth curve will weigh heavily the cons already listed. For a small business owner, however, GAE is a God-send. These folks most often are looking to "the cloud" as a means to more effectively run their business (i.e. sell physical product and services). For the SMB, GAE the pros already listed can be much more valuable compared to the hockey-stick seeking dev, whilst the cons weight in at a fraction of the devs' measure. I don't see the GAE team doing anything related to SMB positioning, so I guess answers like this are me just pulling on Superman's cape, and spitting into the wind. Really GAE should be absolutely ruling the SMB space now. If not (I have no insights re: user base), then its is a greatly lamentable failure.

Answer (score 1):

Con: All your base are belong to us

... On a serious note:

Con: You don't control the environment your application runs in. The same cons as with outsourcing any component. Fun for toys, not for business (yet) IMHO.

Various things like API for Google **proprietary** backends such as their database system and other 'lockdowns' and frameworks that mean your code is tied, in some loose sense to their system can create cost issues later if you want to migrate from GAE. Of course, you *could* abstract these.

I like GAE, AppJet and others. They are cool. But everything has its place. If you want freedom and the ability to control your language's modules, API, syntax/stdlib versions and whatnot ... don't relinquish control to a service provider.

The lack of **standards** for environments and specifications for what your app can expect worries me in the cloud arena.

**common sense** stuff really.

Comment: Please elaborate environment control. Also what are the difficulties in porting your application to some other Domain

Answer (score 1):

You are force to own a cell phone line, and your country+carrier must be able to receive international SMSs.

(I hate cell phones, and my mom's or co-workers won't get the SMSs)

Comment: see nick's response to voyager's answer.  you can get app engine without a phone.

Comment: also, you only need to have a phone to sign up.  not forever.  if you are planning on running any kind of real business, a small startup cost like that is trivial.

Comment: No reply from that form, even after a week or so. And, NO, I don't plan on any kind of real business.

Answer (score 1):

Con: No Other RDBMS or NoSQL databases are not possible ....

Comment: good point, I wish they supported the ORDBMS systems :D

Answer (score -3):

Con: Limited to Java and Python

Comment: Removing the 'Java' part turns this into a Pro.

Comment: It's not true! With Java you can use JRuby for example, or Jython (maybe not) or Scala, Groovy, etc...

Comment: What about the Languages Listed here http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-java/web/will-it-play-in-app-engine?pli=1

Comment: Most are JVM based language. Hmmm...

Comment: By Modifying some part of your code you can deploy many (JVM)languages there

Comment: javascript as well: http://www.appenginejs.org/

Comment: The Go language is supported (in 'experimental mode') as well