# What is the essence of google app engine?

Tags: google-app-engine

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Pros & Cons of Google App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306279/pros-cons-of-google-app-engine)

> Is it a hosting site just like others paid hosting space? Is it just
>   like a ftp server that i can upload files on it? the only difference
>   is it has a unqiue dashboard to configure the database/ others things?

Also, i just get some experience in html/php . Why the app engine require skills in paython/java?? As i know that they are not web language? Thanks for kindly answer my question

To be more precise , can it served as a development tools? or a web space for putting files on it and configure the server behaviour just like appache???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google appEngine is free of cost till some limit (around 500MB I guess). Also the server which you will built to be run on app engine will be either in python/Java.

As far as web programming is concerned the response to the queries of the client can be rendered as HTML/PHP on client side by the client's browser.

In short appengine runs your server part and your browser will be the client. And you have to code the behavior of the server on various responses by the client.
And google appEngines gives u a lot of other facilities as compared to many others.
Refer [Google App Engine](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/whatisgoogleappengine.html)

Answer (score 0):

No one explains it better than Google themselves: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/whatisgoogleappengine.html
It is a platform upon which you can develop web apps, plus have them hosted.

Python and Java are absolutely web languages. PHP is better suited to some functions and not as well-suited to others.